# Gmail is blocking my emails sent to them

Tags: spam, gmail

I believe I got blocked for sending too many emails to one address by gmail. I have an application I made and I had email notifications on. It was sending a lot of notifications recently. I have since altered it so I don't send so many, however it seems I was too late. I got blocked for sending too many emails from my site to my gmail account.

Is there a way to appeal this at all?

```
 host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4002:c07::1b]
    said: 550-5.7.1 [2604:180::1458:e4e6      12] Our system has detected that
    this 550-5.7.1 message is likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of
    spam sent 550-5.7.1 to Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please visit
    550-5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131
    for 550 5.7.1 more information. d5si6473448yhn.57 - gsmtp (in reply to end
    of DATA command)
```

The reason for being blocked is due to sending too many emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At [Gmail Support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839?hl=en) area there's the reference to the daily sending limit, which is 500 messages per day or a huge number of undeliverable messages.

> In an effort to fight spam and prevent abuse, Google will temporarily
>   disable your account if you send messages to more than 500 recipients
>   or if you send a large number of undeliverable messages. If you use a
>   POP or IMAP client (for example: Microsoft Outlook or Apple Mail), you
>   may only send a message to 100 people at a time. Your account should
>   be re-enabled within 24 hours.

As stated, your account should be back within 24 hours. 
If you want to keep using Gmail, you can use [Google Apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en), as the limits are higher (2000).

My recommendation is that you use a professional Email Sending service like [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/pt/ses/).

Comment: I was not sending email via Gmail I was sending email TO a Gmail address.

Comment: The principle should be the same, and the restriction will be removed within a few hours. There's some recommendations from Google on bulk messaging here https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126?hl=en email authentication can also help you https://support.google.com/mail/answer/175365?hl=en

Comment: I am still being blocked despite it being the next day.

Comment: And these emails are simply being sent to my own address, I don't care to use a professional service for this.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Nope it is still blocking it.

Comment: try testing your domain in a Spam checker to see if you're marked as such: http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx or http://www.dnsbl.info/

Comment: I'm not marked in any.

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370620/how-to-stop-gmail-from-marking-mails-sent-by-my-web-app-as-spam

Answer (score 1):

You can increase your ranking by adding a Sender Policy Framework to your domain. See:- http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax